# Symfony 3 api authentication with FR3DLdapBundle, Jwt and FosUserBundle

Tags: api, symfony, token, fosuserbundle, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm trying to auth API and BackOffice users of a Symfony 3 app with a combination of 3 bundles : FR3DLdapBundle, LexikJwtAuthBundle and fosUserBundle. the first step I trying to do is to integrate LexicJwtBundle with fosUserBundle as a provider but every time a 401 error "bad credentials " appear to me , here is my config file :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: ~
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
    public_key_path:  '%jwt_public_key_path%'
    pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: admin200@tls.tt
        sender_name: admin tls

nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
```

security.yml :

```
   # To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                check_path:               /login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: jwt
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ea0a3bab6b4dc3bb4b9f8c54c5c7b6e5139ad444

    jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/private.pem' # ssh private key path
    jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/public.pem'  # ssh public key path
    jwt_key_pass_phrase:  ''                                         # ssh key pass phrase
    jwt_token_ttl:        3600
```

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
api_login_check:
    path: /login_check

# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

I'm testing this url  : http://localhost:8000/login_check with postman to get the token but nothing work ! some help please ?

[image]

Comment: 401 code means that the user is not authentified, and this is so logique, maybe the user "test" is not alreday registred ...

Comment: hi @Bhs thanks for your comment , the user is already registred and exist in the database and it's authenticated but still the same error and no token generated :/ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to send body row by json like that
{"_username":"test",
"_password":"test"}

Answer (score -1):

From the screenshot, it appears you miss the underscore of _username and _password. Maybe that would be enough for the auth to succeed ?

Comment: hi @Mikael , I've tried it with and without underscore , but no token generated and the same error still appear !

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the routing :  @FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml has also a /login_check route. You might want to have a différent path ?

Comment: didn't find the way to do that !!

Comment: Try by just disabling the @FosUserBundle/.../security.xml line (and keep the underscores by the way)

Comment: Thanks @Mikael for your suggestion but when I try to disabling the  @FosUserBundle/.../security.xml line symfony will show an error some thing like there is no route for /login !